# MarginBottom works but PaddingBottom doesnt works on React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

am creating a vertical rectangle shape with  in react Native, so when i apply paddingBottom it doesnt make any changes but when i apply marginBottom is makes the needed change ! why is that ?

My code:

```
<View style={{ 
      width: 35, 
      height: 35, 
      borderRadius: 5, 
      borderColor: 'red', 
      backgroundColor:'red', 
      borderWidth: 1, 
      paddingBottom: 20 }}> 
      </View > 

      <View style={{ 
      width: 35, 
      height: 35, 
      borderRadius: 5, 
      borderColor: 'red', 
      backgroundColor:'red', 
      borderWidth: 1, 
      paddingBottom: 20 }}> 
      </View >
```

As I have applied paddingBottom: 20, its not giving space between both ! but when i apply marginBottom it works ! why is that ?

Reproducing the same in this react platground with web : [Click for reference](https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-ride-fj1dq?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how margin is supposed to behave. It is used to define the space between different elements on a webpage or in this case a screen. If you observe the below diagram you can see padding is used inside the element whereas margin is outside the element and can be used to space elements apart

[image]